# Finding pair of natural numbers such that when used in two fractions, results in natural numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Determine all pairs of natural numbers (a, b) such that $\frac{3a + 8b + 2}{10a + 2b + 1}$ and $\frac{8a + b + 3}{2a + 7b + 3}$ are also natural numbers (including 0).

This implies that gcd$(3a + 8b + 2, 10a + 2b + 1) = 10a + 2b + 1$ so let $3a + 8b + 2 = m(10a + 2b + 1)$.

Similarly, gcd$(8a + b + 3, 2a + 7b + 3) = 2a + 7b + 3$ so let $8a + b + 3 = n(2a + 7b + 3)$.

Then I tried setting up a system of equations to find $m$ and $n$, but it yielded no solutions. It could be that there are no solutions, but I'm thinking that I did something wrong. Does anybody know how to approach this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both fractions are positive for all $a,b\in\Bbb{N}$. Therefore we can deduce that they are $\ge1$.

So $3a+8b+2\ge10a+2b+1$ implying that $6b+1\ge7a$. But we also have $8a+b+3\ge2a+7b+3$, implying that $a\ge b$. Together these imply that $b\in\{0,1\}$ (do you see why?) and I'm sure you can do the rest. There are exactly two pairs $(a,b)$ meeting the requirements.

Comment: Your explanation helped a lot! However, I'm only able to find one pair.

Comment: @grxxes75 You said that this time $0$ is included in the naturals?

Comment: Yes, I know (0, 0) is an obvious solution.

Comment: And if $b=1$, then ....?

Comment: Ah, I got it. I have no idea how I missed that. Thank you so much!